# how to arrange a list in the order of index od another sorted list in python?

Tags: python, list

I have 2 lists say,

```
dates=['4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
events=[a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j]
```

I sorted list dates in chronological order and put the valus in List dates1

```
dates1=['7/6/2014', '7/10/2014', '7/20/2014', '8/3/2014', '8/11/2014', '9/16/2014', '10/14/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
```

now how do I arranges the events in the same chronological order as dates1?

Comment: `sorted(dates, key = lambda i: dates1.index(i))`

Comment: It will be easier to sort `zip(dates, events)` instead of sorting them separately.

Comment: Also, uh, I suspect your life would be easier with `datetime`: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html . And perhaps dictionaries : http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex39.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to use numpy's argsort function, though it requires you to convert your events list to an array.

```
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

dates = ['4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
events = np.array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'])

datetimes = [datetime.strptime(date, '%m/%d/%Y') for date in dates]
events_sorted = events[np.argsort(datetimes)]

print(events_sorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to go about this would be to `zip` both the lists together and then sort them based on the date conversions for the `dates` array.

Example -

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> dates=['4/21/2015', '10/14/2014', '9/16/2014', '7/10/2014', '8/11/2014', '8/3/2014', '7/20/2014', '7/6/2014', '4/21/2015', '4/21/2015']
>>> events=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j']
>>> s =  sorted(zip(dates, events), key = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x[0],'%m/%d/%Y'))
>>> s
[('7/6/2014', 'h'), ('7/10/2014', 'd'), ('7/20/2014', 'g'), ('8/3/2014', 'f'), ('8/11/2014', 'e'), ('9/16/2014', 'c'), ('10/14/2014', 'b'), ('4/21/2015', 'a'), ('4/21/2015', 'i'), ('4/21/2015', 'j')]
```

Then you can get the list of events sorted using list comprehension as -

```
>>> sortedevents = [x[1] for x in s]
>>> sortedevents
['h', 'd', 'g', 'f', 'e', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'i', 'j']
```

What `zip` function does is that it combines the elements at the same indexes from the lists (iterables) provided to it as parameter into a list of tuples (each tuple at ith position containing the combination of elements at ith position from the lists provided in parameter).

Answer (score 0):

This will do it:

```
sortedevents = sorted(zip(dates, events), key = lambda i: dates1.index(i[0]))
```

First we combine the dates and events into matching tuples and then we sort the tuples using the sorted list `dates1`

To get the sorted list of events by itself:

```
events = [e[1] for e in sortedevents]
```

Anand's answer may be preferred since it removes the need to have a separate sorted list of dates, i.e. no need to have `dates1`